# Total order on irrational numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, order-theory, irrational-numbers, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that the set of irrational numbers $\mathbb{I}$ is totally ordered. I almost completed the proof but stuck at the very end...

---

Some theory. The set of irrational numbers $\mathbb{I}$ consist of all possible $A)(A'$ cuts that can be constructed on rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. The $A)(A'$ means there is no biggest element in $A$ class and no lowest element in $A'$ class.

Now we define the **equal** and **bigger** relations between two arbitrary irrational numbers $\alpha = A)(A'$ and $\beta = B)(B'$.

$$ \alpha = \beta :\Leftrightarrow (A=B) \land (A' = B') \qquad \quad \alpha > \beta :\Leftrightarrow B\subset A $$

---

So now I need to prove that the set of irrational numbers is totally ordered:

$$ \boxed{\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{I} : \ (\alpha = \beta) \lor \Big( (\alpha > \beta) \dot{\lor} (\beta > \alpha)\Big)} $$

Comment: Hmm, what's special about irrational numbers here? Show that the real numbers are totally ordered, and that any subset of a totally ordered set is totally ordered.

Comment: @JairTaylor I am trying to conctruct the set of real numbers which is a union of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{I}$. Technically, I don't have $\mathbb{R}$ for this moment...

Comment: The usual Dedekind-cut construction of real numbers constructs all real numbers simultaneously.  If you have rational numbers and irrational numbers you have all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to avoid re-defining rational numbers when constructing $\mathbb{R}$? Usually we don't worry about things like this.  Technically Dedekind cuts give a second construction of the original set $\mathbb{Q}$, as well as the irrational numbers, but we just identify these two constructions.

Comment: I am bit confused right now. My main goal is to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is a Dedekind-continuous set but Dedekind-cuts can only be applied to totally ordered sets. But how $\mathbb{R}$ can be totally ordered if I can't even order the irrationals...

Comment: Applying Dedekind-cuts to $\mathbb{Q}$ shows there are "gaps". We call such "gaps" irrational numbers. Now I think I need to prove that $\mathbb{I}$ is a totally ordered set and construct a new set called $\mathbb{R}$ which is Dedekind-contanuous...

Comment: Applying Dedeking cuts to $\mathbb Q$ produces the set of all Dedekind cuts. Some of these correspond to irrationals, some of them correspond to rationals. We call this set $\mathbb R$. You need to show $\mathbb R$ is totally ordered.

Comment: @JackM yeah but when proving $\mathbb{R}$ is totally ordered we anyways will have to prove that two arbitrary irrational numbers are ordered, won't we? So it doesn't really matter where we prove that they are ordered, in $\mathbb{I}$ or in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sure, in the same way the to prove that every multiple of $4$ is even you "will have to" prove that every *triangular* multiple of $4$ is even, but that doesn't make that a great way to actually structure the proof. I think Jair Taylor's point is that it seems like an unnecessary distraction to focus on the irrationals.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are focusing far too much on symbolic manipulations of logical propositions, treating this like a simple algebra problem which can be "solved" by shuffling symbols around. Consequently you are getting lost in a thicket of symbols.

Let's use the definition of a Dedekind cut that's on Wikipedia. I'll use your $A)(A'$ notation.

> **Definition.** The Dedekind cut $A)(A'$ is a pair of sets of rationals $(A, A')$ such that:
>
> 1. $A$ is non-empty and is not all of $\mathbb Q$.
> 2. If $y\in A$ and $x<y$, then $x\in A$.
> 3. $A$ contains no maximum element.

The only time in your entire question where you seem to use these assumptions is when you mention that if $A\neq B$ then $A'\neq B'$, where $A)(A'$ and $B)(B'$ are Dedekind cuts. Everything else in your reasoning seems to use no other facts about Dedekind cuts besides that a Dedekind cut is an ordered pair of two sets. This is what I mean when I say you seem to be focused too much on simple symbolic manipulation.

So, we have to show that if two Dedekind cuts $\alpha=A)(A'$ and $\beta=B)(B'$ are different, then either $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$. Well, since they're different, we know $A\neq B$. We also know that both $A$ and $B$ satisfy the three properties listed above. How can we use that?

Suppose $A\neq B$. If every element of $A$ is in $B$ then $A\subset B$ and we're done. Therefore let $a\in A$ not be in $B$. It is visually obvious that $a$ must be "to the right" of $B$, in the interval "between" $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In particular we ought to have $a$ greater than every element of $B$, and from there, by point (2) above, we can conclude $B\subset A$. So how can we show this rigorously? Try the following:

1. Suppose $a$ is not greater than every element in $B$. Then show there is $b\in B$ such that $b\geq a$.
2. Deduce that $a\in B$, and therefore by contradiction, the assumption in step 1 was incorrect and $a$ is greater than every element in $B$.
3. Conclude that that $B\subset A$.

Comment: I can't really get why you jump from $A\neq B$ straight to strict subsets (that is not logically correct in my opinion) and refer to something visual... Why can't $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be inequal **and** visually still be in the same place on "number line"? The irrational numbers are something completely different from rational numbers and we should **expect** and **check** every logically possible situation that comes from $A\neq B$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you zero in on a specific point that confuses you? What do you mean by going "straight to strict subsets"?

Comment: I mean that strictly speaking $A\neq B$ by definition means that $(A\nsubseteq B)\lor(B\nsubseteq A)$. There is nothing about strict subset relation $\subset$ in this definition and every other expression which does contain $\subset$ must be strictly proved.

Comment: We know that $\alpha\neq\beta$, and from this *we have to show that* $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$. You are correct that the latter is not an obvious consequence of the former, I just mean that it is what we have to prove.

Comment: Hmm. I think I understand now. The (1.) and (2.) in your solution are excessive since if $a\notin B$ it immediately means $a\in B'$ because all rational numbers must be in either $B$ or $B'$ otherwise $B)(B'$ is not a cut at all. So we now know that $a>\forall b\in B$. So what? In other words can you please describe (3.) in details?

Comment: @CMTV Step 3 of the proof follows from part 2 of the definition. You might want to work it out in more detail.

Comment: Yeah I get it already. If $a>\forall b\in B$ than $B\subset A$ because otherwise there is a $b\in B \land b\notin A \Rightarrow  b\in A' \Rightarrow b > \forall a \in A$ which leads to contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to prove trichotomy by showing that if $\ \alpha\ne \beta\ $ and $\ \alpha\not>\beta\ $ then $\ \beta>\alpha\ $.

If $\ \alpha\not>\beta\ $ then, by definition $\ B\not\subset A\ $, and if $\ \alpha\ne\beta\ $ too, it follows that  $\ B\not\subseteq A\ $.  Therefore $\ B\cap A'\ne\emptyset\ $. Let $\ b\in B\cap A'\ $ and $\ a\in A\ $. Since $\ b\in A'\ $, then $\ b>a\ $ and therefore $\ a\in B\ $. Since this holds for any $\ a\in A\ $, it follows that $\ A\subseteq B\ $, and, since $\ A\ne B\ $, that $\ A\subset B\ $. Therefore $\ \beta>\alpha\ $.

For completeness, I note that I've here used a couple of properties of the Dedekind cut $\ A)(A'\ $ that you didn't mention in your description—namely $\ a'>a\ $ for all $\ a'\in A'\ $ and $\ a\in A\ $, and $\ (x\in A) \wedge (x>y)\implies y\in A\ $.

Answer (score 0):

Pure logical proof.

---

### Lemma 1. "Simple ="

For arbitrary irrational numbers $\alpha = A)(A'$ and $\beta = B)(B'$
$$ (A=B)\Leftrightarrow (A' = B') \Leftrightarrow \alpha = \beta $$

**Proof:**

Lets prove that $(A=B)\Rightarrow (A'=B')$. We assume the negation is true:
\begin{gather*}
(A=B)\land(A'\neq B')\Leftrightarrow\Big( (A=B)\land(A'\nsubseteq B') \Big)\lor\Big((A=B)\land(B'\nsubseteq A')\Big)
\end{gather*}

Dealing with the left bracket: $ (A=B)\land(A'\nsubseteq B') $. It means there is an element $a\in A'$ which is not in $B'$, thus $a\in B$ (by definition of $B)(B'$ being a cut). Since $A=B$ we have $a \in A$. Finally, $a\in A \land a\in A'$ which means $A)(A'$ can't be a cut. We have a contradiction. The same reasoning can be done for the expression in the right bracket.

Finally, both expressions in big brackets cause a contradiction, so our proposal that the negation is true was actually **false**. So we proved $\Rightarrow$. This means both bottom and top classes are equal. By definition of irrationals equality it means $\alpha = \beta$.

The same reasoning can be done when proving $ (A'=B')\Rightarrow(A = B) $.
$\blacksquare$

---

### Lemma 2. "Simple $>$"

For arbitrary irrational numbers $\alpha = A)(A'$ and $\beta = B)(B'$
$$ (B\subset A)\Leftrightarrow (A'\subset B') \Leftrightarrow \alpha > \beta $$

**Proof** is mostly the same as for **Lemma 1**.

---

### Lemma 3

For arbitrary **not equal** irrational numbers $\alpha = A)(A'$ and $\beta = B)(B'$ the following expression is always true
$$ A\subset B \Leftrightarrow B\nsubseteq A $$

**Proof:**

$\Rightarrow$)
$$ A\subset B \Rightarrow B\nsubseteq A $$

We assume that the negation is true
$$ (A\subset B) \land (B\subseteq A) $$

Expanding $A\subset B$:
$$ \underbrace{(A\subseteq B) \land (B\subseteq A)}_{A=B} \land (A\neq B) $$

So we get a contradiction $(A=B)\land(A\neq B)$. Thus we proved $\Rightarrow$.

$\Leftarrow$)

$$ B\nsubseteq A \Rightarrow A\subset B $$

We assume again that the negation is true
$$ (B\nsubseteq A)\land \overline{(A\subset B)} $$

Lets write up what $\overline{(A\subset B)}$ means:

$$ \overline{(A\subset B)} \Leftrightarrow (A\nsubseteq B)\lor(A=B) $$

Now we put this into our expression above:

$$ \Big((B\nsubseteq A)\land(A\nsubseteq B) \Big) \lor \Big( (B\nsubseteq A) \land (A=B) \Big) $$

In the right brackets we have $(A=B)$ which by **Lemma 1** means $\alpha = \beta$ and we get a contradiction (since $\alpha \neq \beta$ by condition).

The expression in the left brackets means that $\exists b \in B \land b\notin A$ which means $b\in A'$ *and* $\exists a \in A \land a\notin B$ which means $a \in B'$. By definition of a cut every element in $A'$ is bigger than every element in $A$ thus $ b > a $. Again, every element in $B'$ is bigger than every element in $B$ thus $ a > b $. So we get
$$ (a > b)\land (b>a) $$

This can't be true because $a$ and $b$ are both **rational** numbers and $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally ordered!

Finally, both expressions in the left and in the right brackets cause a contradiction. Thus we proved $\Leftarrow$.
$\blacksquare$

---

### Proof that $\mathbb{I}$ is totally ordered

$$ \boxed{\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{I} : \ (\alpha = \beta) \lor \Big( (\alpha > \beta) \dot{\lor} (\beta > \alpha)\Big)} $$

**Proof:**

Lets assume we have two arbitrary irrational numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If $\alpha = \beta$ then everything is OK.

Otherwise, $\alpha \neq \beta$.

$$ \alpha \neq \beta \Leftrightarrow (A\neq B) \lor (A' \neq B') $$

There are 3 possible cases here:

1. $(A\neq B)$ and $(A' = B')$
2. $(A=B)$ and $(A'\neq B')$
3. $(A\neq B)$ and $(A'\neq B')$

First two cases immediately lead $\alpha = \beta$ (by **Lemma 1**) which gives a contradiction.
Thus (3.) is the only possible case of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ inequality.

$$ \alpha \neq \beta \Leftrightarrow (A\neq B) \land (A'\neq B') $$

Now we expand $(A\neq B)$ and $(A'\neq B')$:

$$ \alpha \neq \beta \Leftrightarrow \Big( (A\nsubseteq B)\lor(B\nsubseteq A) \Big) \land \Big( (A'\nsubseteq B')\lor(B'\nsubseteq A') \Big) $$

Applying **Lemma 3** results to everty $\nsubseteq$:

$$ \alpha \neq \beta \Leftrightarrow \Big( (B\subset A)\lor(A\subset B) \Big) \land \Big( (B'\subset A')\lor(A'\subset B') \Big) $$

Now we apply **Lemma 2** to both left and right expressions in brackets.

$$ \alpha \neq \beta \Leftrightarrow \Big( (\alpha > \beta) \lor (\beta > \alpha) \Big) \land \Big( (\beta > \alpha) \lor (\alpha > \beta) \Big) $$

$$ \alpha \neq \beta \Leftrightarrow (\alpha > \beta) \lor (\beta > \alpha) $$

The only thing left is to exclude the case when $(\alpha > \beta)\land(\beta > \alpha)$ simultaneously. If so then by definition of $>$ we have

$$ (B\subset A) \land (A\subset B) \Leftrightarrow \underbrace{(B\subseteq A)\land(A\subseteq B)}_{A=B} \land  (A\neq B) \Leftrightarrow 0 $$

So, we proved that

$$\alpha \neq \beta \Leftrightarrow (\alpha>\beta) \dot{\lor} (\beta > \alpha) $$

$\blacksquare$